# How to catch PyGetWindowException when using pygetwindow in Python?

Tags: python

I have a script which uses `pygetwindow` module to do some operations on a specific window. While the script runs, I get the following exception:

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 237, in activate
    _raiseWithLastError()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pygetwindow\_pygetwindow_win.py", line 97, in _raiseWithLastError
    raise PyGetWindowException('Error code from Windows: %s - %s' % (errorCode, _formatMessage(errorCode)))
pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException: Error code from Windows: 0 - The operation completed successfully.
```

I'm okay with the exception occurring but I want to catch this exception explicitly. I have done the following to try and catch this exception:

```
try:
  #implementation
except pygetwindow.PyGetWindowException:
  #handle exception
```

and

```
try:
  #implementation
except PyGetWindowException:
  #handle exception
```

Neither of the above catches the exception. If I use either of the above, I get another exception:

```
NameError: name 'PyGetWindowException' is not defined
```

or

```
NameError: name 'pygetwindow' is not defined
```

I don't want to catch the general `Exception` and then handle it since in case of other exceptions, I want to handle it differently. Is there something wrong in how I'm trying to catch this exception or is there a way to avoid this exception altogether?

EDIT: To be very clear, I have already imported `pygetwindow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

From the [source](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/tree/be242794b08e0d30b27502610c97c8a1640b4e20/src/pygetwindow) file, it was clear that in order to use `PyGetWindowException`, you need to import the exception specifically (and not just `import pygetwindow`). Therefore, in order to catch the exception, one will have to do:

```
from pygetwindow import PyGetWindowException
```

After this import, you can use the exception in the normal way:

```
try:
  #implementation
except PyGetWindowException:
  #handle exception
```

#### Update 2

Another general way to do this would be to [get the exception name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176602/how-to-get-the-name-of-an-exception-that-was-caught-in-python) from general exception and compare.

```
try:
    try:
        #implementation
    except Exception as e:
        if e.__class__.__name__ == 'PyGetWindowException':
             #handle exception
        else:
             raise e

except Exception as e:
    #handle other exceptions except pygetwindow exception
```

#### Original answer (not recommended)

Found a way to solve this question in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735326/10153731).

From the [source](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/tree/be242794b08e0d30b27502610c97c8a1640b4e20/src/pygetwindow) of `pygetwindow`, it was clear that, whenever `PyGetWindowException` is raised, it is accompanied by the text:

> "Error code from Windows:"

which indicates the error code given by Windows.

Based on this information, I did the following:

```
try:
    try:
        #Implementation
    except Exception as e:
        if "Error code from Windows" in str(e)
            # Handle pygetwindow exception
        else:
            raise e
except Exception as e:
    #handle other exceptions
```

This is another way (although the first one and second one are the correct and straightforward solutions) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `import pygetwindow` at the begging of your script. It complains about not knowing what `pygetwindow` is.

Comment: Considering the exception given at the beginning of the post, if I hadn't imported `pygetwindow`, I would be getting a different exception altogether. I got the `NameError` after the other exception occurred, which wouldn't have occurred if I didn't import `pygetwindow` Therefore, it should be clear that I already have imported `pygetwindow`.